# logging runtime php errors

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file which passes a JSON to javascript.

```
$testjson = array(
"result" => true,
"count"  => 1
);
$json = json_encode($testjson);
echo $json;
```

JS:

```
$.get("serverside.php", function(data, status) {
                     console.log((data));
                });
```

The problem is that instead of getting the object, console prints:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' ...
```

I realized it means I have an error in php file. but how should I log in console the runtime php error?

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the underlying PHP errors. It looks like you have `xdebug` installed so all it's letting you know is you have a problem with your code somewhere.

Comment: How should I where is the problem? I am using firefox. Is there any way to see errors in the firefox console?

Comment: Open Firebug, click on the Net tab and the click XHR. When your AJAX runs, it will show you what is being returned.